# Finding lines starting with lowercase letter

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a long text which has some lines are seperated. How can I find the lines starting with lowercase letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure both the "regular expressions" and "match case" options are checked and try this:

```
\r\n[a-z]
```

This will search for a carrriage return (new line) followed by a lowercase letter.

Comment: hello, your code matches both uppercase and lowercase letters. thank you for your answer.

Comment: oh I enabled "match case" and it works fine. thanks a lot

Comment: @onurcano22 I just realized why that was the problem (it was working on mine!) -- I'll edit it now. I'm glad it helped! (although iLoveTux's answer is arguably more elegant).

Comment: This will ignore the first line

Answer (score 0):

Try

ctrl + h

Then make sure that regular expression is checked and use

`^[a-z]`

Answer (score 0):

If you hold ctrl + h and you type `^[a-z]`, it should work, make sure the matches newline option is selected is selected and the regular expression option.

[Notepad++ regex helper](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)